# Google Search API and Get result from specific Website

Tags: google-search-api, google-custom-search

Is it possible for me to get a search results based on a query from specific website using google search api. For example query = "car fix" and only show results from "www.wikihow.com".

I prefer the return in json/html format.

Thanks all.

Comment: `query = "car fix site:wikihow.com"`

Comment: @Nico thx for quick answer, I can work with it, cheers!